# What is diffrence between ? and ? = nil

Tags: swift, option-type

As the title I've just asked, I want to know which case we should use `? = nil`

For example :

```
var text: String? // text will be initialized with nil

var text: String? = nil // text will be assigned to nil
```

So what is the diffrence between them. When we should use `? = nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the Swift Language documentation:

> You use optionals in situations where a value may be absent. An optional says: There is a value, and it equals x or there isn’t a value at all

There is no difference between `?` and `? = nil`. The `? =` syntax allows you to assign a default (a word they should perhaps use in the documentation for the sake of clarity) value of your choosing.

So if *there is no value at all*: `?` or, if *there is a value, and it equals x*, then: `? = <some value>`